# Realm EXC_BAD_ACCESS when querying database

Tags: realm

Im new to realm. I have read the documentation and followed the examples in creating and querying the database. Whenever I run the code below it crashes on the line

> let realm = Realm

I have a view controller that I am trying to query realm like so:

```
            // Get the default Realm
            let realm = Realm()
            // Query using an NSPredicate
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "s3_url = %@", s3_url)
            let medias =  realm.objects(MediaRealm).filter(predicate)
```

everytime i run this i get Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

> let realm = Realm()

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let mediaCollection = MediaCollection()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        loadInitialData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func loadInitialData(){
        //connect to url
        mediaCollection.fetch(onSuccess:{ self.onEventFetched($0) }, onError:{ self.displayAlert($0)})
    }

    func onEventFetched()->Void{
        println("Got stuff")
        println(mediaCollection.models.count)
        processCollection()
    }

    func processCollection()->Void{

        for media in mediaCollection.models{
            let m = media as! Media
            println(m.s3_url)
            println(m.title)
            if let s3_url = m.s3_url{

                //query database, if it already exists dont download it
                // Get the default Realm
                let realm = Realm()
                // Query using an NSPredicate
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "s3_url = %@", s3_url)
                let medias =  realm.objects(MediaRealm).filter(predicate)
                if medias.count == 0 {
                    println("no files found")
                    //downloadFile(s3_url)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show the models that you defined? Because parsing all model to create schema when the first time to access Realm. It probably occurred some error in creating the schema.

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi which is a terrible answer, but probably true, I am getting this and deleting the app does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by me adding new fields to the database and not running a migration. 
Solution was to delete the app and start over.